# DataFrame to CSV save error on Kaggle Python. How to solve?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm trying to save a dataframe containing 20 million rows to a CSV format, with this:

```
df_merge.to_csv('processed.csv')
```

After executing the code, I got this error message: `OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: 'processed.csv'`

What is this and how can I handle it?

**NOTE:** The code is run on kaggle.

Complete error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-1ba18467b457> in <module>
----> 1 df_merge.to_csv('processed.csv',sep='\t')

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in to_csv(self, path_or_buf, sep, na_rep, float_format, columns, header, index, index_label, mode, encoding, compression, quoting, quotechar, line_terminator, chunksize, date_format, doublequote, escapechar, decimal, errors, storage_options)
   3401             doublequote=doublequote,
   3402             escapechar=escapechar,
-> 3403             storage_options=storage_options,
   3404         )
   3405 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/format.py in to_csv(self, path_or_buf, encoding, sep, columns, index_label, mode, compression, quoting, quotechar, line_terminator, chunksize, date_format, doublequote, escapechar, errors, storage_options)
   1081             formatter=self.fmt,
   1082         )
-> 1083         csv_formatter.save()
   1084 
   1085         if created_buffer:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/csvs.py in save(self)
    232             errors=self.errors,
    233             compression=self.compression,
--> 234             storage_options=self.storage_options,
    235         ) as handles:
    236 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py in get_handle(path_or_buf, mode, encoding, compression, memory_map, is_text, errors, storage_options)
    645                 encoding=ioargs.encoding,
    646                 errors=errors,
--> 647                 newline="",
    648             )
    649         else:

OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: 'processed.csv'
```

Comment: have you tried using a relative path?

Comment: No, how do i do it? @nihilok

Comment: See my answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [this](https://www.kaggle.com/questions-and-answers/70138) on the Kaggle support forum just now after Googling your error message. Have you tried using `'./processed.csv'` (relative path)? I've never used it but apparently the Kaggle working directory is `/kaggle/working/` or `'./'`